# Top -p results into file

Tags: top, linux-headers

I want to add my own header to the print out from this command and save to a file:
`top -p 1198172,1198173,1198174.1198175,1198176,1198177,1198178 | awk '{print $1,"---",$9,"---",$10,"---",$12}'`

Comment: Add `> file_name` after the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
(echo "Headers are fun";top -p 1198172,1198173,1198174,1198175,1198176,1198177,1198178 | awk '{print $1,"---",$9,"---",$10,"---",$12}') >file
```

Comment: AskUbuntu does not support asking a second question in a comment.